# Find Maclaurin series of $ y(t)=(t^2+t-2)e^{t^2+1} $

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Find Maclaurin series of
> $$
> y(t)=(t^2+t-2)e^{t^2+1}
> $$

I acted as usual:
$$
y(t)=e(t^2+t-2)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^{2k}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{et^{2k+2}}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{et^{2k+1}}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2et^{2k}}{k!}
$$

And then I got stuck, since I don't understand how to combine even and odd powers together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you do\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{et^{2k+2}}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{et^{2k+1}}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2et^{2k}}{k!}&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{et^{2k}}{(k-1)!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{et^{2k+1}}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2et^{2k}}{k!}\\&=-2e+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac e{(k-1)!}-\frac e{k!}\right)t^{2k}+\\&\phantom=+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{et^{2k+1}}{k!}.\end{align}In other words, the MacLaurin series is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kt^k$ with$$a_k=\begin{cases}-2e&\text{ if }k=0\\\frac e{\left(\frac{k-1}2\right)!}&\text{ if $k$ is odd}\\\frac e{\left(\frac k2-1\right)!}-\frac e{\left(\frac k2\right)!}&\text{ if $k$ is even and }k>0.\end{cases}$$